# Reference table insert point based on another table in QGIS Layout

Tags: qgis, layout-manager, notepad++

I want to create a Layout in QGIS that contains two dynamic Attribute tables (based on an Atlas), stacked one on top of the other.
I want the top table to move based on the size of the bottom one.
I am thinking of extracting the Reference point coordinates and the height of the bottom attribute table and using them to dynamically set the reference point x and y of the top one.
Inspecting the .qgs file in Notepad++ the table is defined as a LayoutItem that has **positionOnPage="54.2278,97.121,mm"**, **size="46.961,36.6704,mm"**, **sectionHeight="36.6704"** "attributes" that I would like to reference.
Is there a function that extracts those attributes/item variables?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See here for dynamic size of text boxes in QGIS print layout: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420016/88814

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try.